# How long can bagged caramel popcorn be at room temp?

Tags: sauce, cream, caramel, popcorn

The caramel sauce has 1c sugar, 6T butter and .5c cream.  Sauce boiled 8-12 minutes; poured over popcorn and baked at 250 degrees for 15 minutes.  This sauce recipe would cover 8-10 qts of popcorn.

The original recipe states that the caramel sauce should be tightly sealed in frig up to 3 wks or freezer up to 2 months.

I'm assuming this popcorn would be eaten in 1-3 days.